# How mongoDb Id is mapped with document stored in disk

Tags: mongodb

Every Db has concept of Id and client uses the id to get the document stored in disk. E.g. MongoDb has id of 12bytes long.
Can someone please help me understand how id is being used to locate the document stored in disk?
Does Id is mapped with location of disk is the only concept being used or is there anything else deep inside which plays more critical role ?

Thanks all for your time!!

Comment: objectId has nothing common with a location on a server disk. By default It's generated based on a timestamp, machine name and PID + some incremented value.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR**
There is no direct correlation between _id value and location of the document on disk.

**Longer explanation**

The `_id` field is a unique identifier for the document in the collection. It is stored with the document like any other user-defined field.

MongoDB uses the WiredTiger storage engine for writing data to disk.  WiredTiger assigns each document in a collection an identifier that it uses internally, but is not exposed and cannot be queried directly.

When writing documents to disk, WiredTiger uses a type of binary tree where the primary key is the internal identifier, and the page size is 32KB.  The current file offset of the root page is recorded with the data file, the root page contains the offset for the next pages in the tree, and so on until the leaf page containing the document is reached.

The `_id` value is recorded both in the document and in an index file (also a tree) which maps to the internal identifier for the document.

When you query for a document by `_id`, the index until is walked to find the internal id of the document, and then the data file is walked to retrieve the document.

The exact location of any page within a file is not static.  When data is updated in WiredTiger a new page is added, then the parent pages are duplicated and updated, including the root.  When a checkpoint completes, the location of the new root page is recorded.

This means that the exact location on disk of a specific document will change *every time* it is update, and will also change if any other document that happens to be in the same leaf page of the tree is update, and may change if the collection is compacted.

After a page is replaced during a checkpoint, that space is marked free for reuse, so a leaf page containing a given document could be moved toward either end of the file when it is rewritten for an update.

Comment: Also OP originally noted "_MongoDb has id of 12bytes long_". This subtly conflates the `_id` field with ObjectIds. ObjectIds are what are used for `_id` by default, but doesn't have to be.